# How do I avoid problems arising from accessing static fields before the class is initialized?

Tags: java, static, classloader

I have this code:

```
public abstract class Person {

    public static final class Guy extends Person {

        public static final Guy TOM = new Guy();
        public static final Guy DICK = new Guy();   
        public static final Guy HARRY = new Guy();
    }

    public static final List<Guy> GUYS = ImmutableList.of(Guy.TOM, Guy.DICK, Guy.HARRY);
}
```

I know, it looks like it should be an enum, and it would be, but it needs to inherit from Person, an abstract class.

My problem is: If I try to access the list of Guys, I'm okay.  But it I try to access any one Guy in particular, I have a problem: `Guy` gets loaded before `Person`.  However, since `Guy` inherits `Person`, `Person` gets loaded, and tries to access `TOM`, but since `Guy` is already being loaded, it can't start to load again, and so we have a null reference.  (And `ImmutableList` doesn't accept null, so we get an exception.)

So I know *why* this is happening, but I'm not sure how to avoid it.  I could move the List into the `Guy` class, but I'll have more than one implementation of `Person`, and I'd like to have a master list of all `Person`s in the `Person` class.

It seems strange to me that it's possible to load a static inner class without loading its containing class, but I guess it makes sense.  Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't keep the guys in `Guy` or `Person`. Keep it in a class `PersonManager` or `People` or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: The reason I like it this way is I can do `Guy.TOM`, which I think has better readability.

Comment: If guy was not static you could just do something like:
`Guy tom = new Guy()`
`List<Guy> guys = new ArrayList<>()`
`guys.add(tom)`

Comment: I suppose you could keep your immutable list in a separate class, like `People.GUYS`, and still keep the individual guys in the `Guy` class.

Comment: @EJP I'd like to keep the instances within their own class, like if I make another Person subclass, I'd have the instances within that class to group them better.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev that might be the best solution.  It preserves the enum-like structure.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then.

Comment: If it's available to you, the best solution might be to refactor your design into a Guy `enum` that inherits a Person interface.  You can provide constant-specific behavior into the enum class instances if necessary.  You'd still be able to refer to instances as Guy.TOM etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep your immutable list in a separate class, like `People.GUYS`:

```
public class People {
    public static final List<Guy> GUYS = ImmutableList.of(Guy.TOM, Guy.DICK, Guy.HARRY);
}
```

This way you can still keep the individual guys in the `Guy` class:

```
public abstract class Person {

    public static final class Guy extends Person {

        public static final Guy TOM = new Guy();
        public static final Guy DICK = new Guy();   
        public static final Guy HARRY = new Guy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution for the sake of solution, this seems working (for single thread)

```
public class Person
{
    static Lazy tom = new Lazy();
    static Lazy cat = new Lazy();

    public static final List<Guy> GUYS = ImmutableList.of(tom.get(), cat.get());

    public static final class Guy extends Person
    {
        public static final Guy TOM = tom.get();
        public static final Guy CAT = cat.get();
    }

    static class Lazy
    {
        Guy v;
        Guy get()
        {
            if(v==null)
            {
                Object x = Guy.TOM; // just to trigger Guy initialization
                if(v==null)
                    v = new Guy();
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

OP's design is inherently recursive. Although Java has a well-defined initialization procedure (which backs off when recursion is detected), the behavior varies depending on which class is initialized first.

The problem is worsened by the requirement that the fields are `final`, which severely limits how we can assign them. Otherwise, we can try `if(null) assign` in multiple places to solve the problem.

The solution posted above essentially uses a temporary variable to workaround the `final` constraint.

---

A modified version using a Map, suitable for more number of fields:

```
public class Person
{
    static Map<String,Guy> cache = new HashMap<>();  // remove after both class are initialized
    static Guy get(String name)
    {
        if(!cache.containsKey(name))
        {
            Object x = Guy.TOM; // just to trigger Guy initialization
            if(!cache.containsKey(name))
                cache.put(name, new Guy());
        }
        return cache.get(name);
    }

    public static final List<Guy> GUYS = ImmutableList.of(get("tom"), get("cat"));

    static{ if(Guy.TOM!=null) cache=null; }

    public static final class Guy extends Person
    {
        public static final Guy TOM = get("tom");
        public static final Guy CAT = get("cat");

        static{ if(Person.GUYS!=null) cache=null; }
    }
```

---

Multi-Threading

It's possible that one thread starts initializing Person while another thread starts initializing Guy. Deadlock is possible, and it does happen in real world. Therefore this design is inherently flawed.

In general, two classes (not necessarily parent-child) having dependency on each other during static initialization is inherently in danger of deadlock.

Application can get away with doing this kind of thing, by carefully triggering initialization in a predictable way at the application start. Still, this is quite dangerous, and it could send someone into days of debugging hell.

Comment: If you refactored your instance initialization to take advantage of the Lazy Double Check idiom (Effective Java, 2nd Ed.), wouldn't that fix the potential liveness problems?

Comment: @scottb - the deadlock is caused by JVM initialization procedure and I don't think there's anything we can do - other than not design a recursive dependency in the 1st place.

Comment: I had thought that this might be just the sort of thing that Bloch was talking about when he mentioned "harmful initialization circularities" in the context of the lazy double check idiom.

Comment: This seems like a huge over-complication to deal with a relatively small problem.  I actually like the solution you had in your first revision better.

Comment: @codebreaker - chicken-egg is not a small problem :) but as I said, it's a solution for the sake of solution.

Comment: @bayou.io This is true.  It just seems like it's more of a cosmetic problem, i.e., there are solutions, they're just mostly ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Is the requirement to use the `Person` abstract class absolute (i.e. is it already a part of legacy code)?

If not then as a recommendation, I suggest that you could refactor the design of your data model into a Guy `enum` class that implements a Person interface.  There are many advantages to this design over the class-based one.

```
public enum Guy implements Person {

    TOM {
        @Override
        public void personMethod1(...) {...} // constant-specific
            :
            :
    },
    DICK {
        @Override
        public void personMethod1(...) {...} // constant-specific
            :
            :
    };

    @Override
    public int personMethod2(...) {...} // general to the enum class
        :
        :
}
```

Note that in this case there is no reason to define a `List` instance with the constant references as the enum API provides the `GUY.values()` method.

It would solve all your initialization woes while still enabling multiple implementations of `Person`.  The downside is in code duplication.  The methods in `Person` will need to be implemented in every enum class (but if there are many methods you can always create a private static helper class and forward method calls to it.)

Comment: I could refactor to use an interface, but I'd have to duplicate the code in the abstract class every time I want to make an enum to inherit from the interface.  I thought about it, and I think it's cleaner to use abstract classes and "pseudo-enums."

Answer (score 1):

change

```
public static final List<Guy> GUYS = ImmutableList.of(Guy.TOM, Guy.DICK, Guy.HARRY);
```

to

```
public static final List<Guy> GUYS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new Guy[] {Guy.TOM, Guy.DICK, Guy.HARRY}));
```

should work (I tested using JDK 8), but is it still meet your requirement?

```
public abstract class Person {

    public static final class Guy extends Person {

        public static final Guy TOM = new Guy();
        public static final Guy DICK = new Guy();   
        public static final Guy HARRY = new Guy();
    }

    public static final List<Guy> GUYS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new Guy[] {Guy.TOM, Guy.DICK, Guy.HARRY}));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  It doesn't throw an exception, but if I access Guy.TOM and then Person.GUYS, I get a list full of nulls.